# ESXi Network adapters into bridge mode from vSphere

Tags: networking, esxi

I have an ESXi machine with a virtual network. I want to have physical computers be able to connect and talk to those virtual machines attached to the virtual network.

I am using vSphere 6.0 and ESXi server. I cannot find how to configure the ESXi box so that the traffic is passed through the physical network adapter on the ESXi box.